# Extracting corresponding elements of sublist

Tags: python

It should work like

```
input: list([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
output: [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

so far i have done this:

```
def list(m):
    list2=[]
    for i in range(0, len(m)):
            list2.append([x[i] for x in m])
    return(list2)
```

It's not working every time..

For example:

it's working for

```
input: list([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
```

but not for

```
input: list([[1,3,5],[2,4,6]])
```

Comment: It's not working because you're getting the length of the list instead of getting length of one of its rows, hence your code will only work for n*n lists.

Comment: ohkkk. Got it. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You would usually do that in Python using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
inp = list([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
output = list(map(list, zip(*inp)))
print(output)
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

The additional [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) call is to convert the elements returned by `zip`, that are `tuple`s, into `list`s, but if you are okay with tuples you can just do:

```
inp = list([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
output = list(zip(*inp))
print(output)
>>> [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Also, the outer `list` is only necessary in Python 3, where `zip` returns a generator, but not in Python 2.

Comment: Look for dupes for common Python questions.